# How to extract buffered data from HTML5 <video> element using blob

Tags: javascript, browser, html5-video, reverse-engineering

It has been a long time for people trying to download videos from those sites not allowing them to do, and now they are using the HTML5  element with blob: URL created from MediaSource. Anyway whatever the source is, the video is buffered
and played in the browser so the data must be somewhere.
There are solutions like https://superuser.com/questions/1033563/how-to-download-video-with-blob-url, which is kind of useful for those sites not strictly protected, not working in the extreme case.
So here let's assume that all scripts are strictly obfuscated with network transmission encrypted, and how should we extract the data buffered to be displayed.
Solutions are not limited, except from reimplementing a browser myself.

*Edit*
The scenario seem like Youtube a lot, but it is impossible to trace anything through the heavily obfuscated script neither the encrypted network transmission.

Comment: what is your question. note: you won't have much luck for cross origin videos

Comment: You could use the browser's network tab and filter traffic by "m3u8" to view the HLS playlists that are called.

Comment: @iangetz, as mentioned in the question let's say that it is just encrypted response

Comment: Can you please provide a sample page you are trying to obtain the HLS playlist URL?